# I can access a public function without ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my project ASP MVC, I can access this function without "ActionResult" by browser URL. I do not know why and how to prevent this ?

**URL: /Home/MyFunction**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
       public void MyFunction()
       { 
          *// Do some thing*
       }
}
```

Thanks in advance

I tried searching but couldn't solve it

Comment: which .net is this? how did you bootstrap the routes? also, try to set it to `private` instead of `public` and see if it help. thing is, if i remember correctly all `public` methods in controller are treated as http endpoints regardless of its return type (on your case it is `void`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [NonAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.nonactionattribute?view=aspnetcore-8.0) attribute to achieve your requirement.

This attribute is used to indicate that a controller method is not an action method.

Use like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [NonAction]
    public IActionResult MyFunction()()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```